# Учтека памяти из-за gif-ки

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Это второй мой вопрос за сегодня. Оказалось (экспериментально подтвердилось), что утечка произодит из-за анимации. Это простенький js, html и css:

```
<img id='myId' src='images/myImg.gif'>
```

Так вот, в первом варианте, я обнаружил js-скрипт, который на лету меняет гифку. Я посчитал, что каждый раз совать `src` это не эффективно, и проблема в этом. Тогда создал 3 картинки и стал скрывать ненужные с помощью того скрипта. К моему удивлению есть меньше памяти это не стало! Гифок три, по 300Кб, 300Кб и 700Кб. За минуту работы эта функци выедает 100 Мб у приложения. Все это работает в WebView (ибо Cardova).

Как по вашему, почему это проиходит? И как это рациональнее исправить?

**Дополнение:**
Эффект никуда не пропадает. Достаточно добавить 1 строку с gif, как начинается утечка. Цикл я разумеется комментирую во время эксперимента.

Comment: Добавьте минимально воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: никакого дополнительного кода. 1 строчка. Стоит ей начать воспроизводится, как я получаю 100 утечки памяти

Comment: Чудес на свете не бывает. Либо что-то в коде, либо смотрите что в GIF находится, но это имеет смысл, если GIF'ка не Ваша...

Comment: Боже, что можно в гиф-то посмотреть?) Гиф как гиф - дизайнер прислал. И проблема точно в этом. Я бы избавился от webView, но здесь им абсолютно все сделано

Comment: Как внедряется произвольный код в GIF: https://marviher.com/topic/6789-zarazhenie-s-pomoschyu-gif
Выглядит так, что у Вас в каком-то цикле что-то происходит. Далее можно долго гадать...

Comment: я дополнил. нет никакой проблемы в цикле.

Comment: А где гифка, может с ней то и проблемы?

Comment: попрую ее очень сильно ужать и проверить снова - отпишусь.Спасибо за наводку

Comment: сделать ее меньше никак не выходит. При самом жестком сжатии - 13%. Решил реализовать сие скриптом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось заменить анимацию на собственный код js. Это оказалось куда более эффективно, чем подкапотная реализация воспроизведения анимации `WebView`. Я бы отказался от него, но приложение целиком есть оно. Что сказать, Cardova 2.9... Для себя я объяснил проблему тем, что анимация разбирается на картинки, которые по очереди показываются. Все кадры держаться в памяти. Если их слишком много, то анимация выжирает вашу память. Так например, после того, как я заменил анимацию на скрипт, вместо 420 Мб памяти, получилось всего 190 Мб.